# Proving the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Step Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, step-function

I'm hoping someone could look over my proof attempt of the following claim.

- **The Statement**

> For the step function $\phi$ on the compatible partition $P=\{p_0,...p_k\}$. Then we say that the function $I:[a,b]\rightarrow$R with $I(t)=\int_a^t\phi(x)$ $dx$ has the following properties:
>
> (a) $I(t)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.
>
> (b) $I$ is differentiable on the union over the partitions $(p_{i-1},p_i)$ and
> $I'(t)=\phi (t)$.

- **Proof Attempt**

I have attempted to prove the (a) and (b) by considering a refinement of the partition such that we define the new partition $\tilde{P}=\{p_0,...$ $(p_j=t)$ $...p_k\}$. If we now evaluate $I$ this gives us the result:

$$I(t)=\int_a^t\phi(x) dx=\sum_{i=1}^j\phi_i(p_i-p_{i-1})$$

*Note: $\phi_i$ denotes the constant value that the step function takes on the interval $(p_{i-1},p_i)$.*

As this is the finite sum of real valued constants, this implies that $I(t)$ is continuous and the derivative exists (being equal to $\phi (t))$.

The claim feels fairly simple, but I'm having trouble showing this more rigorously.

Comment: You haven't shown us the definition you are using for $\int_a^t\phi(x)dx$. I think you should probably be looking at that definition before thinking about refining the partition.

Comment: @RobArthan Apologies, there was a typo. I am using $\phi_i$ to denote the constant that the step function takes on the interval $(p_{i-1},p_i)$. The definition I am using for the integral of a step function is that it should be the sum over the constant on each subinterval multiplied by the width of the subinterval (which I think should be fine?).

Comment: So your new partition should be a partition of $[a,t]$ and you need to explain why its derivative is $\phi(t)$ (because it has the form $c+t$ for some suitable constant $c$).

Comment: @RobArthan So would the solution be of that $I(t)=c+\phi_t (t-p_{j-1})=\phi_tt + C$ where $c$ and $C$ are constants, which is clearly a continuous linear function in $t$ and is therefore also differentiable? Where the derivative ends up being $\phi_t$ as this is the derivative of the above linear equation.

Comment: Typo: sorry, my comment should have read "... has the form $\phi(x) = c + \phi(t)x$ for $x$ in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $t$ ...". Does that make things clearer? (I think your $\phi_t$ should be $\phi_j$ for an appropriate $j$.)

Comment: @RobArthan Should that be the integral of $\phi (x)=...$ over the interval $[a,t]$? Rather than just $\phi (x)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry: $I(x) = c + \phi(t)x$. It's past my bedtime! I think you are on top of this now.

Comment: Great. Thanks for all your help. I've submitted what (I think) should be the correct answer now. Based on our discussion, I think that should be correct, but let me know if you you spot anything that might need clarification or changing. @RobArthan

Comment: Well just use the fundamental theorem of calculus for Riemann integrable functions. If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and $F(t) =\int_a^t f(x) \, dx$ then $F$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ and $F'(c) =f(c) $ if $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: This was from a real analysis course that begins with step functions, then regulated functions, and then Riemann integrable functions. So this result appeared before we had covered Riemann integrable functions @ParamanandSingh

Comment: In that case you may just use the fact that a step function is bounded and hence the integral function $I(t) $ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step One**

First define the new partition on $[a,t]$ which we call $\tilde{P}=\{(a=p_0),p_1,$ [$...$] $p_{n-1}, (\tilde{p}_n=t)\}$.

**Step Two**

If we now evaluate $I$ this gives us the result:

$$I(t)=\int_a^t\phi(x) dx=\sum_{i=1}^j\phi(i)(p_i-p_{i-1})=t\phi(t)+ C $$

*(where C denotes a constant formed by the other terms in the sum).*

**Step Three**

We observe that $I(t)$ is a linear function in $t$ as it is in the form $I(t)= at + C$ where $a=\phi (t)$. And so it is clearly continuous on the $[a,b]$ since it is continuous for all $t\in [a,b]$.

We also note that as it is linear, the derivative is simply $I'(t)=\phi (t)$. Again, since this holds for $t\in [a,b]$, then we are able to conclude that this holds over the each subinterval of $P$.